# how can i use both class and functional component in same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use both class and function in the same file and I am getting a parsing error that

> App is already declared

My code:

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';


class App extends React.Component{
}



function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How can I use both class and functional component in same file?

Comment: You cannot declare two variables with same name in single file.

Comment: You must use either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a class component with a functional component inside of it. Because they work different, for example. Inside a class based component you have the **render** method that returns an html.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ClassComponent extends Component {
 render() {
   return <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
 }
}
```

And in a functional component the **return of the function** is and html.

```
import React from "react";

function FunctionalComponent() {
 return <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
}
```

You can also declare a **functional component** through a anonymous function

```
import React from "react";
 
const FunctionalComponent = () => {
 return <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
};
```

For further information you can check [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-choose-functional-components) or the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/)